# Communication Between Arduino and Processing via Serial is Corrupted

Tags: arduino, processing

I have the following sketch uploaded to my Arduino Uno Rev3:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println("Hello, World!");
    delay(10);
}
```

When I run it, Hello, World! is continually printed to the Serial Monitor as expected.

I have the following Processing sketch:

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial port;

void setup() {
    port = new Serial(this, "/dev/cu.usbmodem1421", 9600);
}

void draw() {
}
```

When I run the Processing sketch, the Serial Monitor output gets corrupted. The clean lines of Hello, World! end up looking like this:

```
Hello, Wold!
Hell, Wrld!
He
Hello, o, Worlorld!
H
Hello,World!
ello World!
Hell, World!
Helo, orld
Hello,Worl!
Hello World!
d!
HellHello, W, World!
```

I would like to communicate between Processing and Arduino via the Serial, but I can't if the output is corrupt. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying that you have the Arduino Serial Monitor open at the same time as running the Processing sketch? If so, you can't do that: you can't have two apps trying to communicate with the Arduino over the same port at the same time.

Also, increase the delay (try 100) - you are flooding the buffer. You don't show the Processing code that reads from the serial port; where is that?

Comment: Looks right yes, seems you are writing to the serial faster than 9600 BAUD can transmit at.

Comment: I didn't realize that you can't run Processing when the Arduino Serial Monitor is open. This is definitely the issue, since I increased the delay to 10000 and still had the same result. I did not include any Processing code to read the data for simplicity, since simply connecting to the port caused the issue. So it appears the correct way to view data on the Serial is directly through Processing.